# JSZipUtils with bearer/token authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the JSZipUtils to pull files from my API and zip the files. The API uses a Token authentication.

However, I noticed JSZipUtils has Basic Authentication hard code in their [library](https://github.com/sebastiansimko/jszip-utils/blob/8ac3c9b3d73c7e383b875996e07c0168d782395c/lib/index.js):

```
if (auth) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
        }
```

without modifying their code, does anyone know how to override this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution where you technically don't modify their code, but override it, is to copy the function from the source file and do like this

```
JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent = function (path, callback, auth){
    //Exactly the same code as in the source file, but with your auth modification
}
```

This should be directly after loading the original class.